# SQL Plus SP2-0606

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Using SQL tool, I want to create a text file that has a VARCHAR records.

Using SQL Developer I have successfully created the output text file by calling a script. But based on my research, the TRIMSPOOl command is currently not supported by SQL Developer, making my output to have trailing spaces.

Here is the code in the script:

```
    spool on
    set echo off
    set verify off
    set feedback off
    set heading off
    set trimspool on
    set termout off
    spool C:\SQLFiles\Output.txt;
    select cust_name || cust_addr as Cust_Details
    from customer_db;
    spool off;
```

I now have the SQL Plus 11g, and I'm trying to run the script i created in SQL Developer. I'm getting an SP2-0606 error, saying:

```
    SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file "on.LST:
```

Based on the research I did, it is because of the Spool command, and I don't have the right to access the default folder??..

Can you help please on what setup I should change do to make the desired result in SQL Plus.

Comment: Hi, sharing the solution i did. I just delete the line for 'spool on'.

Answer (score 5):

You have to put the file name in double quotes - I guess SQLPlus uses C-style escape sequences, giving the backslash `\` a special meaning. Also, you should remove the semicolon ';':

So if you replace

```
spool C:\SQLFiles\Output.txt;
```

with

```
spool "C:\SQLFiles\Output.txt"
```

it should work as expected (if C:\SQLFiles exists and is writable for your account).

*UPDATE*

As @LalitKumarB has pointed out, spool works perfectly fine without the double quotes. The real problem is elsewhere:

```
spool on
```

This tells SQLPlus to create an output file `on` in the current directory. So you'll get this error message if you don't have access to the directory you're starting SQLPlus from.

Comment: I don't think so. SPOOL would work as expected without double-quotation marks. I think issue is with the directory he is using.

Comment: @LalitKumarB: Spot on! sqlplus must be started from a folder where the current user has access to create files.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because of permission issues. Either open your command prompt window in administrator mode or save your file to a location where admin permission is not required.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs,

> SP2-0606 Cannot create file file_name
>
> Cause: The STORE command was unable to create the specified file. There may be insufficient disk space, too many open files, or
>   read-only protection on the output directory.
>
> Action: Check that there is sufficient disk space and that the protection on the directory allows file creation.

My test case shows there is nothing wrong with the spool command. I don't think there is any need of quotes at all.

For example,

**Client: 12c**

**OS    : Windows 7**

```
SQL> spool D:\text.txt
SQL> select ename||to_char(empno) from emp;

ENAME||TO_CHAR(EMPNO)
--------------------------------------------------
SMITH7369
ALLEN7499
WARD7521
JONES7566
MARTIN7654
BLAKE7698
CLARK7782
SCOTT7788
KING7839
TURNER7844
ADAMS7876

ENAME||TO_CHAR(EMPNO)
--------------------------------------------------
JAMES7900
FORD7902
MILLER7934

14 rows selected.

SQL> spool off;
```

And the spool file looks like:

[image]

So it works without any double-quotation marks. I guess  you need to really look at the directory you are using to spool.

Answer (score 1):

this error is just because of , not having `"WRITE" privileges on directory` where you are creating the spool file.

**Solution**
give or ask to give the permission to you who is owner of that directory, if its not owned by you using **chmod**. for ex- full permission to all  `chmod 777 <file/directory name>`

Answer (score -1):

When you get this error check for spaces. For example, below you see both single quotes (') but the first one has a space after it and the second one doesn't.

```
SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file ' E:\SQL CLASS\New folder\sql class prt'
                         SQL> spool 'E:\SQL CLASS\New folder\sql class prt'
```